# AngularJS Navbar UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently creating an angularjs application, and having trouble with my Routes. I'm using the UI-Router and when clicking on my different routes, the page refreshes where the view was, not where the navbar is outside the .

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'd really like the site to start at the top of the page when a route is clicked on.

Here is my route code:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html'
    })
    .state('work', {
        url: '/work',
        templateUrl : 'views/work.html',
        controller: 'workCtrl'
    })
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl : 'views/about.html'
    })
    .state('solution', {
        url: '/solution',
        templateUrl : 'views/solution.html'
    })
    .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl : 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'contactCtrl'
    })
    .state('case_study', {
        url: '/case_study',
        templateUrl : 'views/case_study.html'
    })
     });
```

my index file:

```
    <div ng-include src="'views/global/navbar.html'"></div>

         <div ui-view></div> 

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div ng-include src="'views/global/footer.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Try adding data-autoscroll="false" to your ui-view div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are using Ui-Router 0.2.8 (or upper). If you check [release notes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/0.2.8), you'll find this:

> A much-requested feature: the autoscroll attribute. This adds an autoscroll="expr" attribute to uiView, just like ngInclude has. It also replaces the $anchorScroll call in uiView with a custom
>   provider which scrolls the element attached to uiView into the current view instead. This should allow a more fine-tuning for designers by scrolling automatically to the activate uiView without
>   manipulating anchors. Calling **$uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll()** will restore the current
>   behavior or calling $anchorScroll instead

Comment: who new for angular : please refer:

app.config(['$uiViewScrollProvider', function ($uiViewScrollProvider) {
    $uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll();
}]);

Comment: Probably you should add more detail rather than write "didn't work" (and downvote...)